# Is it possible to port a jQuery module using ProtoType.js to Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I've been the maintainer of an integration module for phpFreeChat since Drupal 5. I ported it to Drupal 6 with no problems, and I tried to port it to Drupal 7, but it hangs when the chatbox starts to load.

phpFreeChat is written with jQuery and the ProtoType.js library. Drupal 7 introduces jQuery into the UI of ALL its pages, and I believe that the reason it won't load is that it is conflicting with this. I looked at the chatbox loaded in Drupal 6 in the Firefox debugger, and then looked at it trying to load in Drupal 7 - both are vanilla installations using Garland theme. The Drupal 7 installation loads 8 jQuery files that are not loaded in Drupal 6. There is a module called Black 'n White that is supposed to let me suppress the loading of JavaScript files and I wanted to see if the chatbox loaded if the loading of these 8 jQuery files was suppressed, but the module didn't work, unfortunately.

phpFreeChat's use of jQuery is extensive - 2 dozen files - and it relies heavily on AJAX. I can't see how to apply the new instructions in Drupal 7 to get around the compatibility problems it introduces to this module. It seems like I'd have to rewrite the entire chatbox program.

If it's possible to port this module to Drupal 7, I'd like to do it. But it appears to me that it's not possible. Maybe, though, I just don't know jQuery well enough to see how to get around the problem. Can someone advise me?